# Printf to Fprintf

Tags: c, printf

I want to create a file with sql commands :

```
CREATE TABLE t1(a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,13153,'thirteen thousand one hundred fifty three');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,75560,'seventy five thousand five hundred sixty');
... 995 lines omitted
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(998,66289,'sixty six thousand two hundred eighty nine');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(999,24322,'twenty four thousand three hundred twenty two');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1000,94142,'ninety four thousand one hundred forty two');
```

It works when I use printf :

```
printf("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(%d, %d, '", i, nbAlea);
NombreVersMots(nbAlea);
printf("');\n");
```

But I can't use fprintf :

```
fprintf(fichier, "INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(%d, %d, '", i, nbAlea);
fprintf(fichier, NombreVersMots(nbAlea)); // <- HERE IS MY PROBLEM
fprintf(fichier, "');\n");
```

I don't find a way to use the second line.

I give you the procedures of you need them :

```
char *one[]={"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
char *ten[]={"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
void pw(long n,char ch[])
{
    if(n>19)
    {
        printf("%s %s ",ten[n/10],one[n%10]);
    }
    else
    {
        if(n) // pour eviter les espaces inutiles quand la boucle n'affiche rien
        {
            printf("%s ",one[n]);
        }
    }
    if(n)
    {
        printf("%s",ch); // affiche 'million', 'thousand' ou 'hundred'
    }
}

void NombreVersMots(long m)
{
    pw((m/1000000),     "million ");
    pw(((m/100000)%10), "hundred ");
    pw(((m/1000)%100),  "thousand ");
    pw(((m/100)%10),    "hundred ");
    pw(((m/1)%100),     "");
}
```

Thanks a lot if you can help me !

Comment: I have no idea about fprintf, but you still can use some char* to store your statements and then you can write into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well problem is that internally `NombreVersMots(long m)` uses `printf` and not `fprintf`. Consider modifying it ( in particular the pw function ) to use fprintf internally too, maybe adding the output stream as a parameter to `NombreVersMots(long m)` as well.

Comment: So, I need to copy the whole procedure with fprintf instead of printf ?

Comment: this is a solution. probably the simplest. and add the additional parameter to NombreVesMots too, to specify which stream fprintf should write.

Comment: @pihug12, no, you don't have to copy the procedure, just change it.  `printf(fmt, ...)` is just like `fprint(stdout, fmt, ...)`.  Pass `stdout` as the argument for your first example and `fichier` as the argument in your second example.

Comment: Thanks ! It compiles fine but it crashes when it writes the file (http://i.imgur.com/VVDK5.png). I give you my code : http://pastebin.com/vA2jhvDz

Comment: there is a cut & paste error, look at the line 66/67 you mismatch the variable to print.

Comment: YEAH ! Thank you so much ! I'm so tired right now. Love you guys ! How can I vote for your comment ? Thumbs up for your awesome help !

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `NombreVersMots` calls `pw` which calls `printf` (not `fprintf`).  You could fix this by replacing `printf` in `pw` with `fprintf` and having `NombreVersMots` and `pw` take a `FILE*` argument which is passed down to `fprintf`.

Comment: Thanks ! It compiles fine but it crashes when it writes the file (http://i.imgur.com/VVDK5.png). I give you my code : http://pastebin.com/vA2jhvDz

Comment: @pihug12, it would be pretty time consuming to track that down without even knowing where it was occurring.  I ran your code but it didn't crash.  A tip though: try to simplify.  Here you copy and pasted a bunch of code when you could have just moved it into a function and given it a FILE* parameter and defined it once.  Now you have to debug twice.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite `NombreVersMots` to use `fprintf()`, and to accept a `FILE *` argument.  Then, if you want to use `printf` at the top-level, call it using `stdout` as the argument.  i.e.:

```
void pw(FILE *file, long n, char ch[])
{
   ...
   fprintf(file, "blah");
}

void NombreVersMots(FILE *file, long m)
{
    pw(file, (m/10000000), "million);
}

NombreVersMots(fichier, 42);  // As before
NombreVersMots(stdout, 43);  // To stdout
```